# How do I resolve Iframe height problem on mobile

Tags: html, css, iframe

I made a banner list thenk put my website, on desktop there is no problem bu on mobile its cutting the banners.

Mobile view

[image: Mobile view]

this is my iframe placement code:

```
<iframe scrolling="no" width="75%" height="670"src="/html/banners.html"></iframe>
<style>
   iframe {
   margin: 0 auto;
   display: block;
   }
   @media(min-width:480px) {
   iframe {
   height:750px !important;
   }
</style>
```

and this is my banner list codes: [Banner list code](https://jsfiddle.net/mqej87o0/)

How can I resolve thisheight issue? can yoou please help me?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can to add a containing wrapper around the iframe.

```
<div class="iframe-container">
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/4aQwT3n2c1Q" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
</div>
```

Then. you can add css.

```
.iframe-container{
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 56.25%;
padding-top: 35px;
height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}
.iframe-container iframe {
position: absolute;
top:0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```